# What is the purpose of the System Settings > Appearance > Background > color picker

Tags: 16.04

In `System Settings` > `Appearance` there is a color picker in the "Background" pane. I think the default is blue in a fresh installation of 16.04. I changed it to green. I see no differences. What is the purpose of this color picker?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The color selector allows you to pick the color(s) for a solid or gradient background.

To see it in action you can select an image with transparency as background (png, svg...), or go to the dropdown for the background of the wallpaper source (upper right corner) and select the option `Colors & Gradients`.

Check [Ubuntu desktop guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/look-background.html) for this and other interesting stuff.

Comment: Thanks, i missed the option's name since I did not use English on my system and translated it on the go...